# Duplicates and version numbers

Tags: discussion, tags, exact-duplicates

There is currently a question, [Creating referenced nodes together with parent node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15995/creating-referenced-nodes-together-with-parent-node), that is tagged with [6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6).

I have the exact same issue, but for a Drupal 7 instance.

Given that the answer could very well be different due to the versions, is it safe to assume that a [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7) tagged question would not be a duplicate?

Would it be proper to add a [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7) tag to solicit additional answers?  The main reason I am asking this, is because I am considering offering a bounty for Drupal 7 solutions.

Comment: Off-topic for this thread, but you have tried [Node Connect](http://drupal.org/project/nodeconnect)? It doesn't offer inline entity additions but takes you off to the node add form for the referenced entity, then take you back to the original node add form once the new entity has been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would say it is acceptable.

As alternative, we could remove [6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6) from that question, and you could offer a bounty for that question explaining that you are giving the bounty to the answer reporting the solution for Drupal 7. You can always assign the bounty to an answer, even if you are not the user who asked the question, and assigning the bounty to an answer is not linked to accepting an answer.
Clearly, in this case you would need to manually assigning the bounty, as you cannot accept the answer.